# How to embed a ggvis chart from an external source in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I got already an answer on pretty much the same topic here [Dynamic ggvis object in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554734/dynamic-ggvis-object-in-shiny), but I am still stacked with a similar piece of code and I don't really understand why.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  fluidRow(titlePanel("My app")),

    fluidRow(
          column(3,
                 tags$h1('Menu'),
                 radioButtons('colors', label = 'select bars color',
                                    c("Red"='red','Green'='green','Blue'='blue'))
                 ),
          column(9,
                 tags$h1("hello"),
                 ggvisOutput('test1'),
                 tags$h2("Chosen color is",textOutput('testText', inline = T))
                 )
    )
   )
  )
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
source("charts.R")
  output$testText <- reactive({ input$colors })
  input_color <- reactive({ input$colors })
  # cars %>%
  #   ggvis(~speed, fill:= input_color) %>%
  #   layer_bars() %>%
  #   bind_shiny("test1", "test1_ui")
  chart1() %>%
    bind_shiny("test1", "test1_ui")
})
```

**charts.R**

```
chart1 <- reactive({
  cars %>% 
    ggvis(~speed, fill:= input_color) %>% 
    layer_bars() 
})
```

I would like to call `chart1` from `charts.R` into `server.R`. Everything works with ggvis if I use the commented code in `server.R`, but it doesn't when I try to call the ggvis function from `charts.R` (as in the uncommented code).

Also, do you think is a good practice to create multiple .R scripts or shall I go for proper modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit 2 things in your script:

1. If you want to split the server or ui code into multiple files, you can use `source(local=TRUE)` to load each file. You can think of this as putting the code in-line, so the code from the sourced files will receive the same scope as if you copied and pasted the text right there. (Shamelessly copied from [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html))
2. Reactive objects should be called with parenthesis only in other reactive expressions or render* expressions

So, your `server.R` to should look like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

source("charts.R", local = T)

output$testText <- reactive({ input$colors })
input_color <- reactive({ input$colors })

chart1 %>%
bind_shiny("test1", "test1_ui")

})
```